# Suggestion needed for Scheduling Service

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer, task

This is my Requirement:
Need application or Task which runs on 24/7 with configurable Time interval(in Delphi).

What i did so far:
So i have decided to go for Windows service.
Then I have created the windows service in Delphi.

The process is
1. Created Windows service Start():

```
procedure TDemo.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
    MyServiceThread := TMyThread.Create(False); //Call the thread
    MyServiceThread.Resume;
end;
```

2. Windows service stop();

```
procedure TDemo.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  MyServiceThread.Terminate;
end;
```

1. Thread's Execute method:

   `procedure TMyThread.Execute;
       begin
           MyTask();
       end;`

MyTask() have some functionality and **it may take 30 secs to 5 min time** to complete the task.

If Now i start the Service,then it call execute method and call MyTask() inside it. Then i t completes task. It will happen only once. Because no Looping at all.

> Then i have created the Task scheduler and set Time interval of 10
>   mins and call the batch file which Starts my Windows service and
>   Stops.

Now Everything is working fine. Every 10 min my tasks was completed.

**What are all the other possibility to do this instead of Task Scheduler?   Is it possible to do inside Service itself?  which one is best method?**

> Thinking and found one solutions:
>     1.Creating the Timer inside the Thread.   But Timer needs to set time as Configurable one.It may be one day or one week and so on..
>
> What is the maximum time support by Timer?
>
> Is it possible to do with timer?
>
> Is any other way to do this?

***Please give me some suggestion to go for better solution.***

Comment: Why not use the system's scheduler? Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I dont't know your Delphi version, but generally `TThread.Resume` is deprecated. You should use `TThread.Start`. But even so, you don't need to start the thread, because it is created with `False` parameter - ie not suspended state.

The `Execute()` executes only once, because you did it so.

The code below is a simple thread that "executes" within a time interval.

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
    private     
      fRefreshInterval: Integer;   // milliseconds
      fTerminateEvent: TEvent;

      procedure SetRI(const Value: Integer);
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;      
    public
      constructor Create(const aRefreshInterval: Integer = 600000);
      destructor Destroy; override;
      property RefreshInterval: Integer write SetRI;
  end;

//// implementation  

constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);  
  fRefreshInterval := aRefreshInterval;  
  fTerminateEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  Priority := tpLowest;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  try
    if not Terminated then
    begin
      Terminate;
      fTerminateEvent.SetEvent;    
    end;

    fTerminateEvent.Free;
  except
    //
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try

      // your code here

    except
      // something bad happened 
    end;

    fTerminateEvent.WaitFor(fRefreshInterval);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SetRI(const Value: Integer);
begin
  InterlockedExchange(fRefreshInterval, Value);
end;
```

If you want to execute your task every XX minutes, you have to keep in mind the time required for your task execution and should do something like:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  taskStartedAt: Cardinal;
  taskDuration: Cardinal;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    taskStartedAt := GetTickCount;
    try

      // your code here

    except
      // something bad happened 
    end;

    taskDuration := GetTickCount - taskStartedAt;

    if (fRefreshInterval > taskDuration) then
      fTerminateEvent.WaitFor(fRefreshInterval - taskDuration);
  end;
end;
```

Anyway, `TTimer` and the `Task Scheduler` are options too.

Comment: Thanks peter for your quick reply.  Is the timer interval is configurable one? Can i use ini file for configure the timer's time interval?

Comment: You can configure the time interval through its `property RefreshInterval` as you like. Also, you can set it initially via the constructor's input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach of creating the timer.

Now if you can schedule task based on system clock (for instance start at 3 PM) then you can use next approach. Instead of changing the timer interval so that it will fire at that specific time you keep your timer at 1 minute interval. And then everytime the timer fires you simply check if the system time is greater than the scheduled time. If it is you do what processing it is needed else you do nothing.

So now you only need one organized list storing all the scheduled tasks in sorted order so that youz don't need to iterate through whole list and check for every task individual if it needs to be executed.

Now if using the systems closk is not an option due the fact that user is able to change it implement your own counter which will be increased everytime the timer fires. So now you only need to adapt your timing logic to your counter system.

EDIT: The approach I'm suggesting is comonly used in time ridden multiplayer browser games where each task takes certain amount of time. So server just stores when certain event would ocur based on when command for some task was isued and how much time takes for that task to compleete.

Answer (score 0):

Having a timer inside your Windows Service is one option. You can also check if your previous instance has completed before kicking off a new one. However, if you have to control the services time to time, this may not be the right option.

Over years, I have found Autosys to be the most useful scheduling agent. It comes with client-server model. So you can control the jobs from your Autosys client tool.

TechScheduler is another option, but now it is very old fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with the "Scheduled Task" approach. It's the windows native approach on
such a task and would you only require to create a console application which is called
every interval you define in the scheduled task.